# SQL query to pull data from three different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to create a SQL query to list all the Nurses in the ‘Sparrow’ Wing ordered by last name, first name.

However, I need to pull Nurse_name and Nurse_surname from the Nurse table, which is linked to another table called Sister by the foreign key Sister_ID, this table is then linked to another table called Wing which has the foreign key Sister_ID.

The nurse is managed by the sister and the sister manages the wing.

Can anyone help me with an SQL query for this? As it is, I am only able to get the data from nurse and sister tables.

Comment: I also have a bridge table called SisterNurse which contains sister_id and nurse_id if this helps

Comment: show the SQL you already have

Comment: I suggest of showing your sample SQL query so that we can help you.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use INNER JOIN: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: [This is the fifth question concerning this homework exercise in the last two hours](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Sparrow)

Comment: Actually I was wrong that was including answers not just questions but still clearly the same homework.

Comment: SELECT NURSE.NURSE_SURNAME, NURSE.NURSE_NAME
FROM NURSE
INNER JOIN WING
ON(WING.WING_ID=NURSE.NURSE_SURNAME)
ORDER BY WING_ID;

This is far from correct, but is the closest I can get with my current knowledge of SQL

Comment: table structure: Sister table - Sister_id (primary key), sister_name, sister_surname, sister_contactnumber, sister_salary

Wing Table - wing_id(primary key), wing_name, number_of_rooms, sister_id(foreign key)

Nurse table - Nurse_id(primary key), nurse_name, nurse_surname, nurse_contactnumber, nurse_salary

SIsterNurse table - SIsterNurse_ID(primary key), Sister_id(foreign key), Nurse_id(foreign key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be aware that you should use the `inner join` to connect tables (but apparently not that the connection needs to be via the related columns) you should apply that knowledge to connect all the tables you need to answer the query.

If you start at the end result and work your way backwards you first chose the columns you need:

```
select Nurse.Nurse_name, Nurse.Nurse_surname
```

and then as they belong to the Nurse table you use that as source in the from clause

```
from Nurse
```

to get the Wing you need to connect the Sister table, but to connect that and Nurse you first need the SisterNurse table joined on the shared attribute

```
join SisterNurse on Nurse.Nurse_ID = SisterNurse.Nurse_ID
```

now you can join Sister on the attribute shared with SisterNurse

```
join Sister on Sister.Sister_ID = SisterNurse.Sister_Id
```

and finally you can join Wing

```
join Wing on Wing.sister_ID = Sister.Sister_ID
```

limit the Wings to the one names 'Sparrow'

```
where Wing.Wing_Name = 'Sparrow'
```

and order the data

```
order by Nurse.Nurse_surname, Nurse.Nurse_name
```

Put it all together and you get:

```
select Nurse.Nurse_name, Nurse.Nurse_surname
from Nurse
join SisterNurse on Nurse.Nurse_ID = SisterNurse.Nurse_ID
join Sister on Sister.Sister_ID = SisterNurse.Sister_Id
join Wing on Wing.sister_ID = Sister.Sister_ID
where Wing.Wing_Name = 'Sparrow'
order by Nurse.Nurse_surname, Nurse.Nurse_name
```

Comment: I really appreciate you explaining each step though, thank you kindly!

Comment: Then maybe your description is incorrect? From the table definitions you provided I'm pretty sure the query should be correct. You should be able to follow the logic and find the error (if any) though.

Comment: Yeah I'll have a play around with it, but I know I'm on the right lines now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much information about the schema involved but maybe this will help:

```
select
  n.Nurse_name
, n.Nurse_surname
, w.Wing_name
, managing_nurse.Nurse_name
, managing_nurse.surname
from
  Nurse n
  join Sister s on n.Sister_ID=n.Sister_ID
  join Wing w on s.Sister_ID=w.Sister_ID
  join Nurse managing_nurse on w.Nurse_Manager_ID=managing_nurse.Sister_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way is to use 'union':

```
select * from (
select nurse_name, nurse_surname, 'nurse' as nurse_type from nurse_table
   union 
select nurse_name, nurse_surname, 'sister' as nurse_type from syster join nurse_table on nurse_table.syster_id = syster.syster_id
   union 
select nurse_name, nurse_surname, 'wing' as nurse_type from wing join syster on wing.syster_id = syster.syster_id join nurse_table on nurse_table.syster_id =  syster.syster_id )
order by nurse_surname, nurse_name
```

Hope this help you!

P.S.
I assume that syster and wing tables have nurse_name and nurse_surname fields.
If not you have to give the same alias to all the selected columns

Comment: This is completely incorrect and nowhere near a solution.

Comment: It doesn't work because the approach is wrong - making minor changes to it won't make it any more correct.

Comment: The 'join' approach show the related name in a single row...I understood that sumaa wants every name-surname tuple in a single row, so the union approach is the only I know to do that in a simple way

Comment: Using joins will show one row for every nurse that is part of the relation.